# I need help to identify the purpose of starthelp.exe

Tags: windows-7

What is starthelp.exe?

It tries to load when I boot/re-boot Windows 7.

I have searched for this file on my computer, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 4):

According to Google it is Malware. Download [MalwareBytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) or a similar application and remove it.

You may need to Boot into `Safe Mode` as the malware may prevent you from running `MalwareBytes`.

Comment: I booted into safe mode and ran Malwarebytes.  It got rid of the ads, but Startup.exe still tries to load at each new boot.  I cannot find that file on my system (I unprotected all folders before search).  Google search shows that none of the big  antivirus players, like McAfee or Symantec, have even heard of this problem.  I guess my question remains, *What is startup.exe and how do you get rid of ALL of it?*

Comment: Startup.exe or starthelp.exe?

Comment: starthelp.exe    if you google it, you will find a site that promises to remove it with their UnHackMe download.  I am unfamiliar with the site, and concerned that well known sites are unaware of this exe program.   http://greatis.com/blog/how-to-remove-malware/starthelp-exe.htm